# Using a class in a namespace with the same name?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, symbols

I have to use an API provided by a DLL with a header like this

```
namespace ALongNameToType {
    class ALongNameToType {
        static void Foo();   
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType::Foo without having to type ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType each time? I tried using `using namespace ALongNameToType` but got ambiguous symbol errors in Visual Studio. Changing the namespace name or removing it gives me linker errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classes and namespaces sharing the same name in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070915/classes-and-namespaces-sharing-the-same-name-in-c)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know what's ambiguous, but you can avoid all conflicts with other Foo functions like this:

```
namespace ALongNameToType {
    struct ALongNameToType {
        static void Foo();   
    };
}

typedef ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType Shortname;

int main() {
    Shortname::Foo();
}
```

Comment: I forgot typedef totally... +1

Comment: you dont actually have to use struct instead of class, do you??

Comment: @2am: you don't have to, you could write `class ALongNameToType { public: static void Foo(); };` if you prefer, but the code in the question needs fixing one way or the other. I generally use `struct` for types with no non-public members. You should lay out the conditions for using `struct` in whatever style guide applies to the code. Some people use `struct` specifically for POD types, or specifically for types whose definition will compile as C, or specifically for types with no user-defined constructors or member functions, or just use it haphazardly for types they consider "simple" ;-)

Comment: `using Shortname = ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType;` is a good alternative nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace myns = ALongNameToType;
```

It seems that you can't alias a class scope like this:

```
// second ALongNameToType is a class
namespace myns = ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType;
```

Maybe you could alias the function it self:

```
namespace foo
{
 class foo
 {
 public:
  static void fun()
  {

  }
 };
}

int main()
{
 void (*myfunc)() = foo::foo::fun;

 myfunc();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType::Foo;
```

if you just want to use it as `Foo()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2008
`error C2885: 'ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType::Foo': not a valid using-declaration at non-class scope`

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to use `using`.  One is for an entire namespace, one is for particular things in a namespace, and one is for a derived class saying it doesn't want to hide something declared/defined in a base class.  You can use the second of those:

```
using ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType
```

---

Unfortunately this isn't working for you (due to the ambiguity of the namespace and the class having the same name).  Combining this type of using with a previous answer should get rid of the ambiguity:

```
namespace alntt = ALongNameToType;
using alntt::ALongNameToType;
```

But once you've renamed the namespace, you really don't need the `using` statement (as long as you're comfortable writing the (shortened) namespace every time you use the class:

```
namespace alntt = ALongNameToType;
alntt::ALongNameToType a;
...
```

Comment: This gives me `error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'ALongNameToType::ALongNameToType'` in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Oh well, it's useful in cases where there isn't ambiguity (eg., "using std::cout").