# Does C++ namespace name and class name duplication lead to conflict?

Tags: c++, class, struct, namespaces, symbols

I was testing the name lookup rules for C++. I've got a simple program having 3 files:

```
$cat testns01.h
struct S{
    static int f(){return 1;}
};

$cat testns02.h
namespace S{
    static int f(){return 2;}
}

$cat testns3.cpp
#include "testns02.h" // namespace
#include "testns01.h" // struct
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = S::f();
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run, I get:

```
$g++ testns3.cpp && ./a.out
1
```

OK, I have 3 questions:

1. name "S" duplication between class name and namespace doesn't conflict?
2. When both has name "S", seems "struct S" has higher priority

If I comment the line of #include "testns01.h", the program will print 2, still OK. So my third question is:

3. Does the c++ standard talk about how name lookup resolves duplicated name duplication?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070915/classes-and-namespaces-sharing-the-same-name-in-c

Comment: @Barmar The difference is, in the link you pointed out, the same name for struct/class and namespae were not defined in the same (global) namespace. I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't even warn about.

Comment: Version of compiler? I can't reproduce it on g++-4.6, g++-6.1.

Comment: GCC 6.3.0:
`error: 'struct S' redeclared as different kind of symbol.  previous declaration 'namespace S { }'`

Comment: "If I compile and run, I get:" ... what do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classes and namespaces sharing the same name in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070915/classes-and-namespaces-sharing-the-same-name-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. name "S" duplication between class name and namespace doesn't conflict?

They do.

> 2. When both has name "S", seems "struct S" has higher priority

It doesn't. (look below)

> 3. Does c++ stardard talke about how name lookup resolves duplicated name duplication?

Yes. Quoting the relevant part of N4140:

> *§3.3.1 [basic.scope.declarative] / 4*
>
> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all
>     refer to the same variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions
>     and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration
>     name is hidden. [ *Note:* **A namespace name or a class template name
>     must be unique in its declarative region**. —*end note* ]

I think you accidentally got your example working for you, because you repeated the include guards. I was able to reproduce the "preference" for class `S` from the question:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
struct S{
    static int f(){return 1;}
};
#endif

#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
namespace S{
    static int f(){return 2;}
}
#endif

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = S::f();
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

[link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PiXydbVuFpXYLbvd)

Comment: Thanks, I found it's a bug of low version of gcc, while higher version of gcc reports this bug.

Comment: Ah, so my guess wasn't correct. It must be a really old version of gcc, though. 4.4.7 on wandbox still errored on this.