# Can a class share a namespace's name?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, symbols

Is the following C++ code valid?

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        // Class code here.
    };
}
```

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        void SomeFunction();
        {
            // Function code here.
        }
    }
 }
```

In other words, can there be a namespace with the same name as a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a class in a namespace with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539333/using-a-class-in-a-namespace-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot have the arrangement you have in your question because there is no way to disambiguate `Bar`.

My compiler says:

```
error C2757: 'Bar' : a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name
```

Comment: The compiler can't just check to see if I'm calling something in the `Bar` namespace or the `Bar` class?

Comment: @Maxpm: The compiler has to disambiguate `Bar` first before it checks inside.  If you call `Foo::Bar::SomeFunction();`, then should the compiler say 'OK' or should it say 'Error' - class Bar has no member?

Answer (score 20):

"can there be a namespace with the same name as **a class**?"

**No**, If they are in the same namespace, as in your case.

Otherwise, yes. Anything can have the same name as anything else if they are in different namespaces. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070915/classes-and-namespaces-sharing-the-same-name-in-c) stackoverflow thread as reference.

Comment: No, that question is about using the same name in *different* namespaces.

Comment: @Mike: I think that Ozair has answered the second question of the OP.

Comment: @quamrana: Yes, I did answer the second part of the question.

Comment: OK. To clarify this answer: anything can have the same name as anything else if they are in different namespaces; a class cannot have the same name as a namespace if they are both in the same namespace.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can have `SomeFunction` be a static member of the `Bar` class.

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        // Class code here.
        static void SomeFunction()
        {
            // Function code here.
        }
    };
}
```

The result is not 100% equivalent to what you want (because of ADL) but the qualified names are what you expect.