# Why can't inner class and outer class have same name?

Tags: c++

My question is simple, why a class and its nested class cannot have same name, but namespaces can?

for example:

```
class Test {
    class Test {};
};
```

is invalid, but

```
namespace Test {
    namespace Test {}
}
```

is valid

Comment: Namespaces don't offer *constructors*. The name `Test` within class `Test` is reserved for that specific use.

Comment: `class Test { struct Wrapper { class Test {}; }; };` should work.  Just need a dummy wrapper between the outer class and and same-named inner class.

Comment: @Eljay Could you explain how does the dummy work in linker?

Comment: The dummy Wrapper acts as-if it were a namespace.  (Before namespaces were in C++, some people used structs for that purpose.)  The linker doesn't care, it just uses the names, and C++ mangles the names (which is implementation specific) to something that could be `$Test` and `$Test$Wrapper$Test`.

Comment: So why don't compiler just generate different names for those constructors, Were C++'s designer  predicted that?

Comment: Because it would be ambiguous, hence the C++ programmer is responsible for making the node not ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `X` already has a member named `X`, referring to itself. This is known as an [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). It's then invalid to add another member with the same name.

Comment: So outer in both local and global scope(the order of global is lower), and outer and inner crash in local scope?

Comment: I do not understand this question, sorry.

Comment: And look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856759/can-a-class-share-a-namespaces-name , the comment under the answer says compiler need disambiguate problem of type first, so why the order of variable is higher?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking, nor how this question relates to your example.

Comment: Don't worry about the first question, just look the last question

Comment: There are no variables in the code you've shown. What do you mean by "order", and what do you believe is higher than what else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219046/discussion-between-alan-jian-and-igor-tandetnik).

Comment: And look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329962/why-can-in-class-initializers-only-use-or, the first answer shows the compiler don't know which Overloaded are we talking.

Comment: If you actually [compile the code](https://godbolt.org/z/nossfz) shown in that answer, you'll see `error: 'Overloaded' is not a type`. Which clearly indicates that the compiler has resolved the name `Overloaded` to the `int` variable and not to the type name.

Comment: So the conclusion is there are two struct X in same local scope?

Comment: Well, there would have been, had your example compiled successfully. But that's not allowed, and so your example fails to compile.