# How to define namespace name same as return type of function in that namespace?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have something like this in my header:

```
namespace Utils
{
    namespace Klass
    {
        Klass fromObject(Object object)
        {
            if (something) {
                return a;
            } else if (something2) {
                Klass b = Klass::initialise();
                return b;
            // ...
            } else {
                return Klass();
            {
        }

        Klass fromString() { ... }
        Klass fromInt() { ... }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call this like this:

```
Klass k1 = Utils::Klass::fromObject(obj);
Klass k2 = Utils::Klass::fromString(str);
```

Problem I have, when I write it this way, is that I get error "*Must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Klass' in this scope*".

Error is fixed when I add the keyword `class`:

```
namespace Klass
{
    class Klass fromObject(Object object)
    {
    ...
        } else if (something2) {
            class Klass b = Klass::initialise();
            return b;
    ...
```

But I don't know how to fix this in the `else` of this function. I cannot write `return class Klass();`.

Is it even possible to do something like this in C++? What I am trying to do is to group my utility functions according to a type they return.

Comment: @dosvarog WHat is the reason to name a class and a namespace with the same name?

Comment: You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856759/can-a-class-share-a-namespaces-name) have a namespace and a class with the same name

Comment: @CoryKramer Not within the same namespace, but you can have a class within a namespace with the same name as the namespace and likely confuse anyone who tries to read it.

Comment: @AviBerger In that case I'm not sure I understand OPs case so they have a namespace `Utils::Klass` and a class `::Klass`? If so I guess they can use fully qualified names to work around this but you're right that they are indeed confusing others, and the compiler in some cases

Comment: You aren't showing where in your namespace setup your class named Klass is defined.

Comment: Namespace names should never *intentionally* be the same as a class name. It might happen, but it's never something you ought to do on purpose. It only creates confusion. If you want to associate a function with a class, make it a (public) static member.

Comment: The question is unclear enough without the intentional name conflict. Remove the conflict, write your code without it, make sure it does what you want. If you cannot, then the conflict has nothing to do with it. If you can, put the conflict back. What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Klass is not defined anywhere in the namespace. It is in another file. Klass is a return type of the function in the namespace that bears the same name.

Comment: Once again. Rename `class Klass` to something else. Does your code work now? If not, you are asking a wrong question. Your problem has nothing to do with a name being the same as some other name.

Comment: Consider naming it KlassNamespace, and use that form as your default naming convention.

Comment: @EvilTeach Everything works if I name my inner namespace KlassX for example. But I don't want to do it like that. I want to name it `Klass`, because then when I call `Utils::Klass::fromObject()`, I know from the name that return type is `Klass`. If I call `Utils::KlassX::fromObject()` it is not clear that return type is `Klass` and not `KlassX`

Comment: @dosvarog Usually you do this by making the functions static member functions of the class, not adding a namespace with the same name.

Comment: "*But I don't want to do it like that.*" You shouldn't. Just make `fromObject` a static member function of `Klass` like everyone else.

Comment: I would, but `Klass` is from external library, I cannot extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `return class Klass();`

---

you can simply write

```cpp
return {};
```

as long as `Klass` doesn't overload for `initializer_list` (or the semantic doesn't change)

---

or you can (fully) qualify the name

```cpp
return ::whatever::ns::Klass();
```

---

---

---

generally, you can introduce alias for internal use

```
namespace Utils
{
    namespace Klass
    {
        using the_Klass = ::Klass;
        the_Klass fromObject(Object object)
        {
            return the_Klass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I ended up using `::Klass` everywhere in my file for referring to real class `Klass` and full path `Utils::Klass::whateverFunction()` for referring to functions in namespace `Klass`. I don't know how I forgot about operator `::`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should be correct inside the block scope of the function:

```
using Klass = class Klass;
Klass b = Klass::initialise();
//...
```

After the `using` type alias `Klass` should always refer to this alias, not the namespace.

That this is unlikely to be a good idea though is already discussed in the comments under the question.